# Compare Dictionary and List

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary ==> `Dictionary<int, cwObject>` styles with different property in cwObject value, and I want to compare it with a list of property and create a new dictionary where the value who equals the list are removed.

```
Dictionary<int, cwObject> styles = stylesOT.Objects;

List<string> elementToRemove.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code and try to explain your problem using your code. Otherwise it's quite difficult we are on the same page and provide any help.

Comment: See http://tinyurl.com/stack-checklist for a quick checklist to run through when posting. I'm sure this will be fairly easy with LINQ when we know what you actually want... (We have no idea what the list would include, or what `cwObject` is...)

Comment: How are the two compared? `int` to `string`? What is in the `string`? What is the format?

Comment: I Want to compare value from Dic styles (string)  who equals to item in the list (string to) and create a new dic where I remove the equals items..Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a hash set from the list for fast lookup (or make it a hash set from start), then you can filter the items from the dictionary and create a new dictionary from them.

For this example I assumed that the `cwObject` has a string property named `element` that you compare to the strings in the list:

```
HashSet<string> remove = new HashSet<string>(elementToRemove);

Dictionary<int, cwObject> remaining =
  styles.Where(o => !remove.Contains(o.Value.element))
  .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete, but i try my best shot by writing the example, try this:

```
//example of class cwObject 
 public class cwObject{
    public string stringtocompare;
    public object anyotherobject;


}
//main process
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //List contains string to remove
        List<string> stringtoremove = new List<string>();
        stringtoremove.Add("stringtoremove");

        //dummy data for cwObject
        cwObject cw = new cwObject();
        cw.stringtocompare = "stringok";
        cw.anyotherobject = "anything";

        cwObject cw1 = new cwObject();
        cw1.stringtocompare = "stringtoremove";
        cw.anyotherobject = 100;

        //dummy data for dictionary to compare
        Dictionary<int, cwObject> dictcw = new Dictionary<int, cwObject>();
        dictcw.Add(0,cw);
        dictcw.Add(1,cw1);

        //new dictionary for container of results
        Dictionary<int,cwObject> filtereddict = new Dictionary<int,cwObject>();
        cwObject cwtemp = null;

        //start enumerating
        foreach (string str in stringtoremove)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, cwObject> entry in dictcw)
            {
                cwtemp = entry.Value;
                if (!cwtemp.stringtocompare.Equals(str)) {
                    filtereddict.Add(entry.Key,entry.Value);

                }
            }
        }

        //output the result
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, cwObject> entry in filtereddict)
        {
            cwtemp = entry.Value;
            Console.WriteLine(cwtemp.stringtocompare);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```